# ASP MVC Model issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model:

```
 public class MenuItem
 {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....   

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PageTemplate { get; set; }

    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the PageTemplate. I need to somehow create a property that list out files from a folder. This property should then be a selectlist in the view, and then saved in the PageTemplate.

What would the proper way of doing this be?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826371/how-to-turn-a-selectlist-into-html-selectlistfor

Comment: Hi, Yes that is the way I should go I think. Atleast when I come back to it.
AT the moment I am not using a viewmodel to display the data, but I should do that - since I have added a property in my main model, which should be in the viewmodel instead.

I did for starters go with sams suggestion for now untill I redo:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model add:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Templates { get; set; }
```

In the action method populate your data to the property:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new MenuItem
    {
        Templates = _yourFilesList.
            .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Title })
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MenuItem item)
{
     var userTemplate=item.PageTemplate; // user's selected item is there
}
```

Finally in the view add this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PageTemplate , Model.Templates)
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. SHould probably use a viewmodel, but thats for next time.:)